# Light rays within a cone

Tags: tikz-pgf

is there a possibility to create rays (lines) in the form of a cone at certain distances starting from a defined point? A manual creation via the respective coordinates seems to be too cumbersome, maybe via an iterating loop? The picture should look something like this:

[image]

Many thanks in advance and greetings

icab

Comment: Could you look at the two solutions you got, upvote and indicate if this is what you are looking for. Maybe you can already use the solution from @Jairo A. del Rio ? -or does it need to be TikZ?

Comment: -also write something about the colors - do you want them fading like the way in your image, or are you just interested in the lines?

Comment: @hpekristiansen Both solutions are great and I'm fine with them. I am just interested in the lines, the coloring is not that important! Thank you both for your solutions!

Comment: Please accept his answer (and upvote).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution only works for a central point for now. I fill a rectangle(with a circle at the end) with an axial shading. To also rotate the shading, I use a canvas transform. This messes with the bounding box, -the reason for `\path (-8,-8) rectangle (8,8);`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-8,-8) rectangle (8,8);
\newcommand{\golden}{180*(3-sqrt(5))};
\foreach \i in {50,...,1}{
    \fill[left color=blue, right color=red!80!black, middle color=yellow, transform canvas={rotate= \golden*\i}] (0,0.05) rectangle ({sqrt(\i)}, -0.05) ({sqrt(\i)},0) circle[radius=0.3];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you accept a Metapost answer, this may be a starting point. Otherwise, I hope another user translate the example to TikZ or whatever else. You'll need `--shell-escape` enabled and Metapost installed (check `mpost` in Terminal or Command Prompt).

```
\documentclass{article}
%Use --shell-escape or -enable-write18 
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{mpost}[name=nice]
%Define yellow just in case. ConTeXt does.
color yellow; yellow := (1, 1, 0);
numeric n, u; n := 100; u := 4mm;
%Helmut Vogel's formulas for sunflowers are a lazy, nice way to fill circles
numeric GoldenAngle; GoldenAngle := 180*(3-sqrt(5));
%Play changing "3u" to move the center.
pair Center, Points[]; Center := (left+up)*3u;
for i = 1 upto n:
    Points[i] := ((sqrt(i)*sind(GoldenAngle*i)), (sqrt(i)*cosd(GoldenAngle*i)))*u;
    draw Center -- (.25[Center,Points[i]]) withcolor blue;
    draw (.25[Center,Points[i]]) -- (.5[Center,Points[i]]) withcolor green;
         draw (.5[Center,Points[i]]) -- (.75[Center,Points[i]]) withcolor yellow;
    draw (.75[Center,Points[i]]) -- Points[i] withcolor red;
endfor
for i = 1 upto n:
    %Change "scaled ..." for larger or smaller dots.
    drawdot Points[i] withpen pencircle scaled 5 withcolor .5[red,black];
endfor
\end{mpost}
\begin{center}
\usempost{nice}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]